# How to access a file from storage in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, storage

I have a file inside my storage folder. 
Located path :

```
storage/app/public/$/10012940/gallery/289sdas98e.jpg
```

$, 10012940 and 289sdas98e.jpg is dynamic and can change.

```
Route::get('storage/{$folderDirectory1}/{$customerReference}/gallery/{file}', function ($filename)
{

});
```

Since its a nested folder I cannot find much on internet as to what the route should look like. Also how to go about doing something like that.

I am trying to find a way to access this path via the route so that I can write a middleware to authenticate before making this accessible to the end user.

I am storing the file inside the storage folder due to the visibility. I would like to control who should have access to viewing the image

Comment: It’s easier to set up a disk and let it handle the rest (https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem). That way you can disregard path in the storage and relay the request as is.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov I want to be able to check who should have access and that's why I stored the file in the storage folder.

Comment: So when trying to access I like to have a middleware to check if they should have access. However I am not sure how the route should look like. As I can't get it working

Comment: Then you should think the question thoroughly and update your post. The better you can formulate it, the more likely the chance people will understand it and be able to answer it in full.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, noted, I have updated my question. Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: To make it more or less unified, I recommend to create a table where you can store information about the file, and a single route with unique file identifier (for example, a UUID), by which user can access it. Using this scheme you will be able to add authorization as per standard with Laravel framework and perform access control through it. User, who uploaded the file, can be the owner, and the entry in files table can be treated as a resource with access controls associated with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205965/discussion-between-dark-illusion-909099-and-daniel-protopopov).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a route name. 
For instance, in your view: href="{{ route('assets.show', $asset) }}". 
In your AssetController@show, simply return Storage::download($asset) for instance.
Then use your middleware to authorize or not the access to the show method.

Comment: I will be showing this image in an image slider. So I need to be able to show the path won't I ?